# TensorBoard is overlaying multiple graphs

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

I save a summary writer in `./some-directory-for-summaries` and then type into the shell `tensorboard --logdir="./some-directory-for-summaries`, and I see my graph. Then I do the same thing with `./some-directory-for-summaries-2` and I'm seeing both graphs, instead of only the latter one. How can I fix this? I understand you can restart the kernel or something?

Apologies if this has been discussed here; I didn't find any answers by searching.

Comment: Please provide a minimal code example.

Comment: @Zvika Sure, do you want the Python code that I used to save the log? I don't think the problem lies there--the log is being saved OK.